# How to Calculate StartDate and EndDate in SQL from Employment Facts and Update It with IsManager Flag from Employee table

Tags: sql

I have two SQL tables: one containing employment facts, and the other with employee information, including an IsManager flag. My goal is to calculate the StartDate and EndDate based on the employment table and update it with changes in the IsManager flag.

The employment facts table (Dim.Employment) has the following columns

| EmploymentKey | EmployeeID | EmploymentStartDate | EmploymentEndDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 212513 | 8673 | 2017-02-03 16:40:46 | 2017-12-07 03:04:37 |
| 277512 | 8673 | 2017-12-07 03:05:37 | 2018-02-07 03:03:16 |
| 295600 | 8673 | 2018-02-07 03:04:16 | 2018-03-01 10:08:28 |
| 300362 | 8673 | 2018-03-01 10:09:28 | 2019-01-31 14:43:40 |
| 624046 | 8673 | 2019-01-31 14:44:40 | 2021-03-15 04:06:59 |
| 952895 | 8673 | 2021-03-15 04:08:00 | 2021-11-26 06:31:12 |
| 1445647 | 8673 | 2021-11-26 06:32:12 | 2021-11-26 11:39:02 |

In this table, changes in roles result in new rows with unique keys, start dates, and end dates. However, when an employee becomes a manager, this change is recorded in the employee table (Dim.Employee) without creating a new row in the employment table. Instead, a new row is created with a new IsManager flag and updated start and end dates in the employee table.

The employee information table (Dim.Employee) contains the following columns:

| EmployeeKey | EmployeeID | IsManager | ManagerStartDate | ManagerEndDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 17155 | 8673 | 0 | 2017-02-03 16:40:42 | 2021-04-29 04:14:57 |
| 107935 | 8673 | 1 | 2021-04-29 04:15:57 | 2021-04-30 04:15:27 |
| 161150 | 8673 | 1 | 2021-04-30 04:16:27 | 2021-04-30 08:17:33 |
| 177765 | 8673 | 1 | 2021-04-30 08:18:33 | 2021-05-02 04:10:43 |

The calculation of StartDate and EndDate should follow these rules:

StartDate should be equal to EmploymentStartDate, but if the IsManager flag changes from 0 to 1, I want the ManagerStartDate to be the EndDate of that row. A new row should start with ManagerStartDate, duplicating the EmploymentKey (this is acceptable since it's a fact table).
I'm seeking guidance on how to achieve this efficiently and accurately using SQL. While I've made an attempt, my current query takes all the start and end dates from both tables, which is not the desired outcome.

Desired Result

| EmploymentKey | EmployeeID | EmploymentStartDate | EmploymentEndDate | IsManager |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 212513 | 8673 | 2017-02-03 16:40:46 | 2017-12-07 03:04:37 | No |
| 277512 | 8673 | 2017-12-07 03:05:37 | 2018-02-07 03:03:16 | No |
| 295600 | 8673 | 2018-02-07 03:04:16 | 2018-03-01 10:08:28 | No |
| 300362 | 8673 | 2018-03-01 10:09:28 | 2019-01-31 14:43:40 | No |
| 624046 | 8673 | 2019-01-31 14:44:40 | 2021-03-15 04:06:59 | No |
| 952895 | 8673 | 2021-03-15 04:08:00 | 2021-04-29 04:15:57 | No |
| 952895 | 8673 | 2021-04-29 04:15:57 | 2021-11-26 06:32:12 | Yes |
| 1445647 | 8673 | 2021-11-26 06:32:12 | 2021-11-26 11:39:02 | Yes |

Here's the query I've tried so far:

```
`SELECT
    E.EmploymentKey,
    E.EmployeeID,
    (SELECT MAX(i) FROM (VALUES (E.EmploymentStartDate), (EE.ManagerStartDate)) T(i)) AS StartDate,
    (SELECT MAX(i) FROM (VALUES (E.EmploymentEndDate), (EE.ManagerEndDate)) T(i)) AS EndDate,
    EE.IsManager
FROM Dim.Employment E, Dim.Employee EE
WHERE
    EE.ManagerStartDate <= E.EmploymentEndDate
    AND EE.ManagerEndDate >= E.EmploymentStartDate
    AND E.EmployeeID = EE.EmployeeID`
```

I'd greatly appreciate any help or suggestions on constructing a SQL query to achieve the desired result.

Comment: Please update your question with enough sample data for the source tables to illustrate the possible scenarios and also show the result you want to achieve. As an aside, your really ought to learn ANSI JOIN syntax, the comma-separated syntax you are using hasn't been good practice for 30+ years

Comment: Could the person get demoted, causing the manager flag to turn from 1 to 0?

Comment: Are there no current managers or employees? (Everyone have end dates.)

Comment: Yes, you could get demoted @isolated

Comment: If you change role within the company you get a new employment. so the last end date you have is your resignation date. This is just one person, all of it